# How to know the current CVS branch in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

I have created a new CVS branch in Intellij, by doing :

- *Right Click* in the parent project
- *CVS*
- *Create branch*
- Enter branch name
- Select ***Override existing*** and ***Switch to this branch***
- *OK*.

Everything is fine but there is no way I can verify that I am in the new branch I have created.

I want to commit to this new branch. How to make sure that I am commiting in the right branch ?

I mostly use git and I know in Intellij that you can see the current branch you are working on, but there is no such thing in CVS.

Thx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

CVS root (branch) in use is shown under the Root Switches group in the Local changes tab.

There is also a request to add the branch information to the Commit dialog
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141642